# How to call Azure PowerShell Module commands in Azure Functions 3.x PowerShell 7?

Tags: azure-functions

I need to run Azure PowerShell Module commands (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/install-az-ps?view=azps-5.2.0) scripts in an Azure Functions 3.

I prefer not to run `Install-Module` on every function call. I expect there is a better way of doing it. Azure PowerShell Module is fairly big.

I am going through the following documentation and I am not able to find any reference on how to call Azure PowerShell Module commandsL
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-powershell?tabs=portal

How to call Azure PowerShell Module commands in Azure Functions 3.x PowerShell 7?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need to use `Install-Module` in this case, currently, when you create the powershell function in the portal, it will install the `Az` module for you by default via the [Dependency management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-powershell?tabs=portal#dependency-management) feature.

You could check the `App files` blade in the portal to make sure your function app was configured correctly, if not, change them like below.

**`host.json`**

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "managedDependency": {
    "Enabled": true
  },
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[1.*, 2.0.0)"
  }
}
```

**`requirements.psd1`**

```
@{
    # For latest supported version, go to 'https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Az'. 
    'Az' = '5.*'
}
```

**`profile.ps1`**

```
if ($env:MSI_SECRET) {
    Disable-AzContextAutosave -Scope Process | Out-Null
    Connect-AzAccount -Identity
}
```

With the settings above, the function app will install `Az` module for you automatically and login `Az` module with [MSI(managed identity)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/overview) of your function app(command in `profile.ps1` did it), it is convenient.

To use `Az` commands in the function, you just need to enable the MSI for your function app and [assign the RBAC role to your MSI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/quickstart-assign-role-user-portal)(depend on specific case, e.g. if you want to list all the web apps in your subscription/resource group, you need give the role like `Reader` to your MSI at the subscription/resource group scope).

[image]

Then in your function code, just use the `Az` command directly without anything else.

*Sample:*

```
$a = Get-AzWebApp -ResourceGroupName joyRG
Write-Host $a.Name
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

In your Azure Functions workspace you have a `requirements.psd1` which lists dependencies, the only default module that it imports is the Az module.

As this is available when the host starts you should just be able to use auto-loading by utilising the Az commands in your function run.ps1.

If you only need a subset of Az modules then you can be more specific in your requirements.psd1 file.

```
'Az.Accounts' = '1.9.5'
'Az.Resources' = '2.*'
```

This is listed in the docs here: [Azure Functions Developer Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-powershell?tabs=portal#dependency-management)