# Azure Function - Connect-MSolservice error

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory, azure-functions

Today, I've created an Azure Function to connect to Office365.

This is the code, which it works on my PC:

```
#Input bindings are passed in via param block.
param($Request, $TriggerMetadata)

#Import-Module AzureAD -UseWindowsPowershell
Import-Module MSonline -UseWindowsPowershell -Force

$PWord = ConvertTo-SecureString –String "MyPass" –AsPlainText -Force
$Credential = New-Object –TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential –ArgumentList "MyTenantAdmin", $PWord

#Connect-AzureAD -credential $Credential
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
Connect-MSolService -credential $Credential
```

However, when I try it on the Azure Function, I obtain this error:

> 2022-12-28T20:45:09Z   [Error]   ERROR: Authentication Error: Unable
> to complete authentication request (potentially a proxy issue)
>
> OriginInfo            : localhost Exception             :
> Type                           : System.Management.Automation.RemoteException
> SerializedRemoteException      : System.Exception: Authentication Error: Unable to complete authentication request (potentially a proxy
> issue) --->
> Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AdalException: User
> realm discovery failed
> at Microsoft.Identity.Core.WsTrust.CommonNonInteractiveHandler.d__5.MoveNext()
> in
> D:\a\1\s\src\Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory\Core\WsTrust\CommonNonInteractiveHandler.cs:line
> 74
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
> at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)
> at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.Internal.Flows.AcquireTokenUsernamePasswordHandler.d__5.MoveNext()
> in
> D:\a\1\s\src\Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory\Internal\Flows\NonInteractive\AcquireTokenUsernamePasswordHandler.cs:line
> 77
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
> at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)
> at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.Internal.Flows.AcquireTokenHandlerBase.d__60.MoveNext()
> in
> D:\a\1\s\src\Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory\Internal\Flows\AcquireTokenHandlerBase.cs:line
> 241
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
> at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)
> at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContext.d__39.MoveNext()
> in
> D:\a\1\s\src\Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory\AuthenticationContext.cs:line
> 542
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
> at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)
> at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContextIntegratedAuthExtensions.d__0.MoveNext()
> in
> D:\a\1\s\src\Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory\Features\WinCommon\AuthenticationContextIntegratedAuthExtensions.cs:line
> 59
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
> at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)
> at Microsoft.Online.Administration.Automation.CommonFiles.AuthManager.AuthenticateUser(AuthenticationContext
> ac, PSCredential cred) in
> X:\bt\1225946\repo\src\dev\PowerShell.V1\modules\psmodule\CommonFiles\AuthManager.cs:line
> 115
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
> at Microsoft.Online.Administration.Automation.CommonFiles.AuthManager.ProcessADALException(AdalException
> aeGeneral, AuthenticationContext ac, IDictionary`2 accessTokens) in
> X:\bt\1225946\repo\src\dev\PowerShell.V1\modules\psmodule\CommonFiles\AuthManager.cs:line
> 529
> at Microsoft.Online.Administration.Automation.CommonFiles.AuthManager.AuthenticateUser(AuthenticationContext
> ac, PSCredential cred) in
> X:\bt\1225946\repo\src\dev\PowerShell.V1\modules\psmodule\CommonFiles\AuthManager.cs:line
> 136
> at Microsoft.Online.Administration.Automation.ConnectMsolService.MsolCmdletProcessRecord()
> in
> X:\bt\1225946\repo\src\dev\PowerShell.V1\modules\psmodule\Cmdlets\Connect-Service.cs:line
> 247
> SerializedRemoteInvocationInfo : System.Management.Automation.InvocationInfo
> ErrorRecord                    :
> Exception             :
> Type                           : System.Management.Automation.RemoteException
> SerializedRemoteException      : System.Exception: Authentication Error: Unable to complete authentication request
> (potentially a proxy issue) --->
> Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AdalException: User
> realm discovery failed
> at Microsoft.Identity.Core.WsTrust.CommonNonInteractiveHandler.d__5.MoveNext()
> in
> D:\a\1\s\src\Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory\Core\WsTrust\CommonNonInteractiveHandler.cs:line
> 74
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
> at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)
> at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.Internal.Flows.AcquireTokenUsernamePasswordHandler.d__5.MoveNext()
> in
> D:\a\1\s\src\Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory\Internal\Flows\NonInteractive\AcquireTokenUsernamePasswordHandler.cs:line
> 77
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

The user has not MFA enabled.

Comment: The credential that you pass should be obtained using `Get-Credential` cmdlet, instead you are just passing an object obtained from New-Object.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-powershell?tabs=portal#dependency-management 

you can add module into requirement.psd1 file.
Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65311813/how-to-call-azure-powershell-module-commands-in-azure-functions-3-x-powershell-7

Comment: Also , you can set identity for the Azure AD.

Answer (score 0):

Enable ***"System assigned identity"*** under `Identity in Function App` to register with `AzureAD` when running inside`Azure functions`. It will then grant all permissions/scopes required to operate with `AzureAD`-related modules.

To run `connect-MsolService`, `MsOnline`(Connecting to 365) module needs to be added in `requirements.psd1` under `App files` in Azure functions. comes under Azure Acitve directory Module.

[image]

check the version compatibility for `Msonline & Powershell`
Add `64 bit` version installer to handle binaries for the online office 365 modules.

`FunctionApp -> Settings -> Configuration`:

[image]

After checking all the above conditions try executing the same script to connect `Msolservice`.

***Other approach:***

As detailed in the [article](https://gcits.com/connect-azure-function-office-365/), I created a triggered function and connected to MsolService (office 365) with FTP hostname.

***Function Properities in Portal:***

[image]

Install `Msoline` module in local folder and deploy it to azure. Add username & password credentials in local path and mention that path in script to get the encrypted values.

`FunctionApp -> Configuration -> Application settings`:

[image]

Script:

```
param($Request, $TriggerMetadata)
$ModuleName = 'MSOnline'
$ModuleVersion = '1.1.*'
$user = $Env:user
$pword = $Env:pword
$path = "C:xxxx"
Import-module $ModuleName
$pWord = ConvertTo-SecureString –String $pword –AsPlainText -Force
$Credential = New-Object –TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential –ArgumentList $user, $pWord
Connect-MsolService -Credential $credential
```

***Got successful response as shown:***

[image]

***Monitor Log check:***

[image]

Comment: I've tried to follow your instructions, but the problem is still appearing.
I've tried to do this Function both in Visual Studio Code (in local) and directly in Azure Portal. When I make it from Visual Studio Code, in my local, the Function works perfectly. When I upload the Function to Azure, or when I develop the Function directly on Azure Portal, the problem is again the same.
It's like is been a proxy between Azure and Office365 don't let me to connect, but my Function doesn't have any proxy or similar.